# Show in look up field only values by specific values in look up list

Tags: list, lookup-column, custom

I have two custom lists (Customer, Contracts).

Customer list contains: Name, Address, Active (yes/no)
Contract list contains: Name, Customer (lookup field), Contract

When I add a new contract I want see only all Customer they have the status active=yes.

It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a filtered lookup column for this:

1. Refer below blog:
   http://www.sharepointsiren.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2007-2010-2013-filtered.html
2. or created filtered lookup using SP designer:
   http://sharepointbergen.blogspot.in/2007/04/creating-filtered-lookup-fields-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field in Customer List say `IsActive` with the formula `=IF([Active]="yes",[Name],"")`

Add a lookup column in Contract List say `Customer` to the Customer and get the information from `IsActive` Calculated field. This Customer lookup field will now display only Active Customer names.